# recover AWS account to delete running services

Tags: amazon-web-services

I had an AWS account. Today I received an email from AWS says that my Free Tier limit is almost finished and I  will charge if the limit exceeded, as shown below.

[image]

Actually I didn't use these services at all.
I am worried to charge if the limit is exceeded.

So, to avoid this, I deleted the entire account.

## My question is:

Are these Free Tier services will be automatically get deleted when I closed the account? Or I will be charged for that too after exceeding the limit?
If yes, please tell me how I can recover my account so that I can stop these services?

Comment: If you genuinely closed the AWS account, the services should all have stopped.

Comment: It might take some time for resources to be deleted after an account is closed. However, you should be able to ask for a refund if such usage leads to extra costs for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Yes I officially closed my account. I followed steps on this link to close it.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/

However, when I closed it, I was not removed my credit card information and not stopped the Free Tier running services. So, I am worry if these services will still running even after I closed the account and I will be charged from the Card monthly :(

Comment: @MohsenAli You should read that page. It says "Before you close your AWS account, back up any resources or data you want to keep", which heavily implies they go away. It also links you to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/closed-account-bill/, which indicates that "all resources on your account are marked for deletion, and on-demand billing for your resources stops".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/closed-account-bill/

> When you close your AWS account, all resources on your account are marked for deletion, and on-demand billing for your resources stops.